# How to customise autoref label

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumerate, itemize

In the output, I get

> In section 1 ... In item 1.1

I want:

> In section 1 ... In question 1.1

This is my script:

```
\documentclass[journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
    \section{Listing}\label{sec:first}
    In \autoref{sec:first} ... In \autoref{question1} \par 
    
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item First
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\theenumi.\arabic*),leftmargin=*]
            \item First First \label{question1}
            \item First Second
        \end{enumerate}
        \item Second
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\theenumi.\arabic*),leftmargin=*]
            \item First First
            \item First Second
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `\renewcommand*\Itemautorefname{question}` before `\begin{document}`. See documentation on [`hyperref` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf), page 20. Note that this changes every autoref of a label to list item.

#### Update

To make the reference format different from label format, use option `ref` from `enumitem` package.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\setlist[enumerate, 2]{
  label=\theenumi.\arabic*),
  ref=\theenumi.\arabic*,
  leftmargin=*}

\renewcommand*\Itemautorefname{question}

\begin{document}
    
    \section{Listing}\label{sec:first}
    In \autoref{sec:first} ... In \autoref{question1} \par 
    
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item First
        \begin{enumerate}%[label=\theenumi.\arabic*),leftmargin=*]
            \item First First \label{question1}
            \item First Second
        \end{enumerate}
        \item Second
        \begin{enumerate}%[label=\theenumi.\arabic*),leftmargin=*]
            \item First First
            \item First Second
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried it but if the authoref with question 1.1, it reference it as question 1.1.) (i.e. it adds the round bracket and I do not want this). I just need the reference to be like: in question 1.1.

Comment: @seq Answer updated.